# Notebook-like background for a TextBox in a Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create an application to take notes for windows phone 8.1
I want to give the user,a notebook type of feel.
For this I have created the UI for notes, the XAML is:

```
<Grid Margin="0,12.333,0,-0.333">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/notebookpaper.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="{x:Null}" Text="" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,96,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="480" Width="340" BorderThickness="0" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" FontFamily="Arial" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" AcceptsReturn="True" FontSize="24.8"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Date : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="246,10,0,0" Height="20" Width="59"/>
</Grid>
```

The image notebookpaper.jpg looks like this:
[image]

When user types in the text in text box, it looks like:
[image]

The problem is that, some characters appear a little above the line, some exactly on the line etc. which looks odd. Also, when I try to scroll, UI appears as:
[image]

The text appears striked out, as only the text scrolls and not the background image.
Also I want to be able to provide user a list of 5-6 fonts out of which they can select which one to use for typing the notes.

What should I do, so that the text appears properly aligned and text scrolls properly.
Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Instead of a background raster image, you could use XAML vector drawings that you can scale or stretch according to the text font's properties. (Though I am not sufficiently knowledgeable with this to give a solution.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems:

1. Varying line height
2. Scrolling doesn't match the lines

To solve the first problem, you can probably work with [TextBlock.TextLineBounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.textlinebounds), talked about a bit in [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/11/xaml-text-improvements-in-windows-8-1/) and the [TextLineBounds enumeration documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.textlinebounds.aspx). This only seems to apply to TextBlocks, so you might have to swap between a TextBlock and TextBox as users edit their text.

To solve the second problem, the [TextBox styles and templates page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710191.aspx) has a lot of helpful info. It looks like you can make your `ImageBrush` the background of your control by overriding TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush. If that doesn't work when focused, you may have to take the entire template given on the linked page and edit it to put your image in the background (there's a lot of XAML, but you should just be able to put your image in BackgroundElement or just before it).

If it still doesn't scroll, you can try setting `ScrollViewer.Background` instead; if that doesn't work, you'll need to handle the `ScrollViewer.ViewChanging` or `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` events (probably by overriding it) so that it you can transform the background image by the amount of pixels the scrollviewer has moved.

You can also find the ScrollViewer in your code-behind (and skip dealing with the template) by using [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper). This would allow you to set the background of the `ScrollViewer` and/or subscribe to its events. This however is more brittle than the other methods and is usually a last resort.